# Exception "String cannot be of Zero length"

Tags: c#, string, stream

We are trying to read each word from a text file and replace it with another word.
For smaller text files, it works well. But for larger text files we keep getting the exception: "String cannot be of zero length.
Parameter name: oldValue "

```
void replace()
    {
        string s1 = " ", s2 = " ";
        StreamReader streamReader;
        streamReader = File.OpenText("C:\\sample.txt");
        StreamWriter streamWriter = File.CreateText("C:\\sample1.txt");
        //int x = st.Rows.Count;
        while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            char[] delimiterChars = { ' ', '\t' };
            String[] words = line.Split(delimiterChars);
            foreach (string str in words)
            {
                s1 = str;
                DataRow drow = st.Rows.Find(str);
                if (drow != null)
                {
                    index = st.Rows.IndexOf(drow);
                    s2 = Convert.ToString(st.Rows[index]["Binary"]);
                    s2 += "000";                                        
                   // Console.WriteLine(s1);
                   // Console.WriteLine(s2);
                    streamWriter.Write(s1.Replace(s1,s2)); // Exception occurs here
                }
                else
                    break;
            }
        }
        streamReader.Close();
        streamWriter.Close();
    }
```

we're unable to find the reason.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may be getting an empty string when splitting by space. Check to see if you don't have any place where there are two consecutive space characters.

Comment: In the future, please include a stack trace of the exception, and if possible, point out the line at which the exception is raised. That usually identifies the source of the problem quickly instead of making people have to analyze your program to figure it out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you do your [`string.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) you may get empty entries if there are multiple spaces or tabs in sequence. These can't be replaced as the strings are 0 length.

Use the overload that strips empty results using the [`StringSplitOptions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringsplitoptions.aspx) argument:

```
var words = line.Split(delimiterChars, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 5):

The exception occurs because `s1` is an empty string at some point. You can avoid this by replacing the line

```
String[] words = line.Split(delimiterChars);
```

with this:

```
String[] words = line.Split(delimiterChars, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 4):

You want to change your Split method call like this:

```
String[] words = line.Split(delimiterChars,StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 2):

It means that s1 contains an empty string ("") which can happen if you have two consecutive white spaces or tabs in your file.